# Recall User Form Position

Tags: forms, position, registry

Haven't been able to locate many examples on the internet and absolutely nothing on the forum regarding saving the position of a User Form for reload.

This macro is seen on several websites :

```
Copy to clipboard
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position") = "" _
    And GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position") = "" Then
    Me.StartUpPosition = 1 ' CenterOwner
Else
    Me.Left = GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position")
    Me.Top = GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position")
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    SaveSetting "My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position", Me.Left
    SaveSetting "My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position", Me.Top
End Sub
```

However ... it isn't working here.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very obvious ... except I overlooked it and the few samples on the internet did not mention this :

The StartUpPosition of the userform must be set to "0" (zero). Here is the edited macro :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position") = "" _
        And GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position") = "" Then
        Me.StartUpPosition = 1 ' CenterOwner
    Else
        Me.StartUpPosition = 0
        Me.Left = GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position")
        Me.Top = GetSetting("My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    SaveSetting "My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Left Position", Me.Left
    SaveSetting "My Settings Folder", Me.Name, "Top Position", Me.Top
End Sub
```